My Google and phone was hacked
My Gmail account was hacked. And everytime I create a new account it was always been hacked. I just saw odd Google app in my phone, Like accounts.google.com thing. So I assume someone stole my phone and Gmail account to navigate and control how I should use it and my way of logging in. I need help. I really do not know what to do. There are important files stored in my drive. How to recover my account.
I do not use Google it tool, because my account is a personal account it was synch with other important account.
